# Defining a complex polynomial with certain roots

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

How can i define a complex polynomial, with real coefficents $a_{0}$ and the form $p(z)=a_{2}z^2 + a_{1}z + a_{0}$  with the roots being at the same time  $z_{1}=1-i$  and 
 $z_{2}=-1+i$,

Comment: Do you want all the coefficients to be real, or just $a_0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a quadratic polynomial $p(z)=a_2z^2+a_1z+a_0$ with roots $z_1,z_2$, we have that $\frac{a_0}{a_2}=z_1 \cdot z_2$ and $-\frac{a_1}{a_2}=z_1+z_2$. So we have the following equations
$$
\frac{a_0}{a_2}=z_1 \cdot z_2=(1-i)(-1+i)=2i \\
-\frac{a_1}{a_2}=z_1+z_2=(1-i)+(-1+i)=0
$$
Hence $a_1=0$ and we are left with $\frac{a_0}{a_2}=2i$. Since we want $a_0$ real, we can choose $a_0=2, a_2=-i$ and thus $p(z)=-iz^2+2$.